# jquery search filter between 2 tables

Tags: jquery

hi I have a problem in filtering two tables,
I search a code in stack overflow and I got it working

but I found out if I add another table and duplicate the process 
I always end up with only one table that can be filtered

here is my code for 2 tables :

```
var $rows = $('#table1 tr');
   $('.search1').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
   });

    var $rows = $('#table2 tr');
   $('.search2').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
   });
```

only #table2 is working

here is my html

TABLE 1 ----------------------------------------------------

```
 Search: <input class="search1" type="text" />
                 <div id="content_table_database">
                  <table id="table1">
                  <?php

                  include('connection.php');
                  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shipments WHERE carrier_short_name !='' group by carrier_short_name ORDER by carrier_short_name ASC  " );

                                            while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                            {

                                                ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td style=" text-align:center; width: 25px;">
                                                <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $test['carrier_short_name']; ?>" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                <?php echo $test['carrier_short_name']; ?>
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>


                  <?php }
                  ?>
                  </table>
```

TABLE 2 -----------------------------------------------------------------

```
Search: <input class="search2" type="text" />

                 <div id="scac_code_database">

                 <table id="table2">
                  <?php

                  include('connection.php');
                  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shipments WHERE carrier_short_name !='' group by carrier_short_name ORDER by carrier_short_name ASC  " );

                                            while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                            {

                                                ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                <td style=" text-align:center; width: 25px;">
                                                <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $test['carrier_short_name']; ?>" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                <?php echo $test['carrier_short_name']; ?>
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>


                  <?php }
                  ?>
                  </table>

                 </div>
```

Comment: Use distinct variables for the rows of your tables and not `$rows` for both. Right now `$rows` will only contain the rows of `#table2` because of [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable `$rows` two times, with different meanings.
Change `var $rows = $('#table2 tr');` with another name `var $rows2 = $('#table2 tr');`

Comment: For the reason check -> [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)